# What is the difference between {} and ->{} in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, reference

So if I have some data object and I want to access whats inside the element of that object

Whats the difference between

```perl
$Data{isEnabled})

$Data->{isEnabled}
```

my data is basically like this

```perl
for my $characterData (@{$AllCharacters->{'characters'}}) {
$Data{isEnabled})

$Data->{isEnabled}
```

and i want to access certain elements of my characterData but I'm not sure when to use

```
$Data{isEnabled})
```

vs

```
$Data->{isEnabled}
```

Like for example why does the first print work but the second fails?

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;


my %info = (NAME => "John", HOST => "Local", PORT => 80);

print $info{PORT};
print $info->{PORT};
```

Comment: You might want to check [the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

Comment: @GMB I've read it already and am having a hard time understanding the difference. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The first expression accesses a key within a hash:

```
my %data = (is_enabled => 1);
print $data{is_enabled}), "\n";
```

In the second expression, `data` is not a hash, but a *hash reference. It would typically be declared as:

```
my $data = { is_enabled => 1 };
```

Since this is a reference, we need to use the dereferencing operator (`->`) to access the hash content:

```
print $data->{is_enabled}, "\n";
```

If you are iterating through an array of hashes, as your code seems to show, then each element is a hash reference. You need to use the second syntax:

```
my @all_data = ( { is_enabled => 1 }, { is_enabled => 0 } );
for my $data (@all_data) {
    print $data->{is_enabled}, "\n";
}
```

You can read more about references in [the `perlref` documentation page](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
$Data->{isEnabled}
```

is equivalent to

```
${ $Data }{isEnabled}
```

I prefer the "arrow" notation, but it serves my explanation better to compare

```
$Data{isEnabled}
```

with

```
${ $Data }{isEnabled}
```

In the first case (`$Data{isEnabled}`), we are accessing an element of a hash `%Data`.

In the second case, we also appear to have a hash lookup, but we have a block (`{ $Data }`) where a name would normally be expected. It is indeed a hash lookup, but instead of accessing a named hash, we are accessing a referenced hash. The block (or the expression to the left of the `->`) is expected to return a reference to the hash the program should access.

A reference is a means of referencing a variable through it's location in memory rather than by its name. Consider the following example:

```
my $ref;
if (condition()) {
   $ref = \%hash1;
} else {
   $ref = \%hash2;
}

say $ref->{id};
```

This will print `$hash1{id}` or `$hash2{id}` based on whether `condition()` returns a true value or not.